# VM image for data science projects

Tags: python, r, tools

As there are numerous tools available for data science tasks, and it's cumbersome to install everything and build up a perfect system.

Is there a Linux/Mac OS image with Python, R and other open-source data science tools installed and available for people to use right away? An Ubuntu or a light weight OS with latest version of Python, R (including IDEs), and other open source data visualization tools installed will be ideal. I haven't come across one in my quick search on Google.

Please let me know if there are any or if someone of you have created one for yourself? I assume some universities might have their own VM images. Please share such links.

Comment: Although this question could be viewed as borderline offtopic I somehow find it a good one for the site IMHO.

Comment: In addition to the awesome comments, there's a (somewhat older) blog post comparing several different solutions: http://jeroenjanssens.com/2013/12/07/lean-mean-data-science-machine.html

Answer (score 13):

There is another choice which popular recently: docker(https://www.docker.com). Docker is a container and let you create/maintain a working environment very easily and fast.

- install essential tools for data science in python

  - https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/ceshine/python-datascience/
- use r language to do data science

  - https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker

Hope that would help you.

Answer (score 12):

If you are looking for a VM with a bunch of tools preinstalled, try the [Data Science Toolbox](http://datasciencetoolbox.org/).

Comment: Interesting project (+1). Thank you for sharing! It might be easier to use it than to figure out why Docker didn't want to work on my Win 7 laptop (see above). However, it still might be a good idea to learn Docker, considering recent trends.

Comment: Nice information. Comparing to vm tools, it needs some time to understand how docker operates. If you are already familiar with vm, it's a good idea to use this toolbox. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. It is definitely interesting. But I don't see how someone can use it without a graphical interface. I would need R-studio, and PyCharm for Python.( iPython notebook is there). I will need to play with a bit to understand it completely.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh I was able to finally get docker to work on my Windows 7 machine by regenerating the certificates
`docker-machine regenerate-certs`
I hope that helps :)

Comment: @R.K.: Thank you for letting me know. I will give it a try when I'll get a chance (it might take a while, though, as there are some higher priority matters waiting to be taken care of).

Answer (score 8):

While *Docker* images are now more trendy, I personally find *Docker* technology not user-friendly, even for advanced users. If you are OK with using *non-local* VM images and can use *Amazon Web Services (AWS) EC2*, consider R-focused images for data science projects, pre-built by Louis Aslett. The images contain very recent, if not the latest, versions of *Ubuntu LTS*, *R* and *RStudio Server*. You can access them [here](http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI).

Besides main components I've listed above, the images contain many useful data science tools built-in as well. For example, the images support LaTeX, ODBC, OpenGL, Git, optimized numeric libraries and more.

Comment: Thank you so much for mentioning this option. I will definitely give it a try. However, I want an image that has exactly like this AMI, but can be run with VirtualBox on my laptop.

Comment: I watched a tutorial recently about Docker, tested it  and found it easy to understand. What part did you find not user-friendly?

Comment: @JeanVids: You're very welcome. I understand your desire to have a local VM - that was the reason I've tried Docker on my computer. I will let you know, if I find a VirtualBox VM image focused on data science (hopefully, R-based).

Comment: @RobertSmith: It is easy to understand until things don't work. I've tried to install and use Docker toolset some time ago, but I was unable to get it installed completely (used several tutorials, including the official one, plus lots of Internet searching, but to no avail). I don't remember exactly, but the issue was pretty technical, which resulted in inability to even run Docker virtualization software on my computer.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh Maybe Docker has been improving lately because I had very good experience. It was very easy to install (at least, on Linux) and I was able to test the main features without any issues.

Comment: @RobertSmith: I understand. Perhaps, the problem was that I was trying to set it up on my Windows machine. Anyway, I will give it a try some time later. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh Yes, that might be the main problem. Unfortunately there are many issues when installing this sort of thing on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try Cloudera's QuickStart VM?:

- http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/downloads/quickstart_vms/cdh-5-3-x.html

I found it very easy to run it and it includes open source software such as [Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) and [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/).

Answer (score 5):

Today I used [this repository](https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-spark) and built it with docker. It is a docker image building spark based on Hadoop image of the same owner. If you to use spark, it has a python api called [pyspark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/).